# How To Change the Default Program for a Specific File

Tags: windows-7

Is it possible to change the default program that a **particular file** opens with ?

Ex: Can i set `Notepad++`as the default program for **one particular text file** and have the rest of the text files opened normally with `Notepad` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these text files share the same extension, you can't.

I'm afraid you have to fall back on right-clicking your particular file and select *Edit with Notepad++* or – if it's always the same file on the same location – you could create a batch file.

Comment: I searched a little more and apparently as you said, I can't do that. But props for the batch file idea. That's just what i wanted ~almost~ :D